# How to create a flexible extension method for generic lists?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, extension-methods, generic-list

I have 2 objects Project and License. They both inherit from the object Entity (abstract class).

Now I have an extension method "GetNewId" that contains logic to get the next id in a list of entities.

I've defined this method as an extension method, but the problem is that List (which is also a list of entities) and List don't see this method.

I guess that this problem will occur with any generic list containing objects that inherit from the same base class.

Is there a solution for this problem?

edit: working in C#

Comment: What programming language are you talking about?

Answer (score 3):

What class/interface is your `GetNewId()` method an extension of?

If you make it an extension of `IEnumerable<T>` - where T is restricted to be derived from your `Entity` base class - you should be able to use the extension method on any collection like class containing `Entity` based objects:

```
public static GetNewId<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence) where T : Entity {
    // your implementation of GetNewId here
}
```

The `Cast` method (from `System.Linq`) is also defined on `IEnumerable<T>` (but on any type T, no restrictions), hence you can use it on your `licenses` instance.

Comment: Your example contained `Tedu.LicenseWebsite.Core.Model.Entity`. You do know about the `using` statement and namespaces...?